# Use Google Translation API with localhost

Tags: google-translate, api-key, google-translation-api

Is there a chance to use Use Google Translation API without getting a key when you are developing your app on localhost?

I was hoping for something like this to work 'https://www.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2?key=**localhost**&source=en&target=de&q=Hello%20world&q=My%20name%20is%20Jeff';

Answer (score 2):

This is working for on chrome:
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-translate/aapbdbdomjkkjkaonfhkkikfgjllcleb

Also, S3.Google Translator for Firefox is working. Auto Detect language was not working in this. Once I selected language to translate from to English then it worked.

Comment: Thanks. I couldn't get the page translated normally since it was running on localhost. This fixed it.